# Not getting the value at email template using PHP

Tags: php, email

I have an issue while sending email to user using PHP. I am binding some value inside the email template but not getting those value inside the template while that sent to user's inbox. I am explaining my code below.

```
$msgSub="Login credentials and verification link for Spesh";
$u_name='Username-"'.$email.'"';
$u_pass='Password-"'.$password.'"';
$url='http://oditek.in/spesh/mobileapi/categoryproduct.php?item=4&acn=2&email='+$email;
ob_start();
include "verification.php";
$msg_body=ob_get_clean();
$is_send=sendMail($email,'info@thespesh.com',$msgSub,$msg_body);
```

> verification.php:

```
<br /><br />
<b><?php echo $u_name ?></b><br /><br />
<b><?php echo $u_pass ?></b>
<b><?php echo $url ?></b>
<br /><br />



function sendMail($to,$from,$subject,$msg_body){
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\n";
 $headers .= 'From: '.$from . "\n";
 $id=mail($to,$subject,$msg_body,$headers);
 if($id){
  return 1;
 }else{
  return 0;
 }
}
```

Here I am getting value for `$u_name and $u_pass` but for `$url` the value is coming `0`. In the first file I have already declared the value for `url`. The value of url should come.Please help me.

Comment: Please show the content of this sendMail() function

Comment: @ObjectManipulator : I posted the content of sendMail() function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is obviously on the way `$url` is set:

```
$url = 'http://.../categoryproduct.php?item=4&acn=2&email=' + $email;
```

(I removed some unimportant part of the first string to let the issue come into focus).

The [addition operator (`+`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) computes **the sum** of its operands. If the operands are strings they are first converted to numbers. When a string is converted to a number, only the maximum-length prefix of the string that looks like a number is used, the rest is ignored. In this code the two strings start with letters, not digits, that's why they both are converted to `0` (zero).

To concatenate strings, use the [concatenation operator (`.`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
$url = 'http://oditek.in/spesh/mobileapi/categoryproduct.php?item=4&acn=2&email='
       . $email;
```